# How to access "Foursquare Userless Venues API v2" via JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, foursquare

I am trying to access the venues on Foursquare by using their userless API formula on my ASP MVC map application but couldn't manage it working.

My code is:

```
var fsObj = [];
var url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&query=' + type + '&radius=' + distance + '&intent=browse&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&v=20120304';
$.getJSON(url, {}, function (data) {
    venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];
    for (var i = 0; i < venues.length; i++) {
        var fsRes = {
            'Id': venues[i]['venue']['id'],
            'Name': venues[i]['venue']['name'],
            'Latitude': venues[i]['venue']['location']['lat'],
            'Longitude': venues[i]['venue']['location']['lng'],
            'Type': type,
            'Vicinity': venues[i]['venue']['location']['address'],
            'Reference': "Foursquare"
        };
        fsObj.push(fsRes);
    }
    printMap(fsObj);
});
```

As you may understand: I am getting lat, lng and distance values from the map. Also trying to print the endresult.

When I use same url on browser it is getting the results but in this code unfortunately not. It makes me to think that may be the json request is not good becase when I try to put a breakpoint at printMap line; it even doesn't stop. Am I doing something wrong?

Any helps will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much.

**NEW APPROACH BUT STILL NO CHANCE:**

```
var getFoursquare = function (p, g, q) {
    var lat = p.lat();
    var lng = p.lng();
    var url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=' + lat + ',' + lng + '&query=' + q + '&radius=' + g + '&intent=browse&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&v=20120305';
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data.response.venues, function (i, venues) {
            fsRes = {
                'Id': venues.id,
                'Name': venues.name,
                'Latitude': venues.location.lat,
                'Longitude': venues.location.lng,
                'Type': q,
                'Vicinity': venues.location.address,
                'Reference': "Foursquare"
            };
            fsObj.push(fsRes);
        });
        printMap(fsObj);
    }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) { alert(event); alert(jqXHR); alert(thrownError); });
}
```

Comment: could you perhaps provide more detail? What does the response look like and are there in errors on the console?

Comment: When I use same url on browser it is getting the results but in this code unfortunately not. It makes me to think that may be the json request is not good becase when I try to put a breakpoint at printMap line; it even doesn't stop. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thing is this is a cross domain call and is most likely designed to be used from a server proxy. perhaps do a `console.log(data)` using Chrome browser and view the console to see what happens to the request. I suspect however its getting blocked due to the SOP. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy There are many answers on SO talking about SOP and javascript calls.

Comment: yeah I guess you are right but I don't want to use a 3rd party flash solition for proxy purpose cause I am planning to implement this on a mobile solution also. :( It is too sad

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> venues = data['response']['groups'][0]['items'];
> ```

There's no 'groups' field in the response object. You want

> ```
> venues = data['response']['venues'];
> ```

You probably wrote this code before you started specifying a versioning ID. Groups were dropped in June 2011, so all calls with a recent version ID no longer return them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've tried with different codes also but still no chance :( I am going to add my other approach to the question.

Comment: Can you add a check to see if you're getting a valid json object back at all before you try parsing it?

Comment: sorry for this late reply. i've put a check and it gives error code 405: Method Not Allowed

Comment: that would be why you're not able to parse the JSON, you're getting an error back from the server, I would make sure that your request is properly constructed before trying to parse the response in your code. Just paste the request URL in your browser and make sure that you get good looking JSON back. tools like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc will help you scan the JSON object more easily.